# info for RTC module needed

Tags: rtc, documentation

I have this RTC module by [MikroElektronika](http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/rtc/):

[image]

I need a schematic and/or user manual but it's no longer on the MikroElektronika website. (There's a similarly looking PCB but it uses a different IC than the PCF8583 used here.) 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try asking MikroElektronika.

Comment: @LeonHeller: I did, but until now got no reply.

Answer (score 2):

For a very simple board like this it should take less than an hour to make a sketch of the circuit. Even less time with the use of an ohm meter to confirm some connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why would I reverse engineer it if somebody might have all the documentation?

Comment: Also, the diode types aren't readable without desoldering

Comment: What are you trying to do? Build more of these or simply make use of the one that you have? As for documentation get a data sheet for the PCF8583 and you get 37 pages that tell you more than you  need to know to use this module!

Comment: One last thing. Several of the modules at the site you linked in your question have exactly the same chip on them AND they are offering an RTC examples link. What more could you ask for?

Comment: What more could I ask for? A schematic without having to reverse engineer. Who says the other modules have the same schematic?

Comment: You have already spent more time worrying about it than diving in and getting on with your project like I suggested.

Comment: These modules are nothing but the reference design in the ic datasheet....